# Fast way to recover the leading singular vectors

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, svd

Given a matrix, is there a fast algorithm to recover the leading singular vectors, i.e. find the closest rank-1 matrix closest to the matrix in Frobenius norm?

By fast algorithm I mean anything faster than:

```
  [U, S, V] = svd(A);
  A1 = U(:,1)*S(1,1)*V(:,1)';
```

Comment: The leading singular vector can be obtained by calculating `A^large_power` (and taking the norm).

Comment: This question is much more suited for [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). In short, I think you are looking at [ARPACK](https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/applications.html)-type library.

Answer (score 0):

So the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) can be used for this purpose:

```
C = A*A';
v1 = power_method(C);
v2 = nanmean(A./v1,1)';
A1 = v1*v2';
```

but in my experiments it is not consistently faster than the highly-optimized full svd:

```
[U,S,V] = svd(A); 
A1 = U(:,1)*S(1,1)*V(:,1)';
```

but I guess for large matrices it may work better.